# Store data into three dimensional array PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a set of data stored in database table `tb_Alt` as follows :

```
id_alt |name|distance|price|quantity
1      |A   |   2    | 10  | 3
2      |B   |   4    | 123 | 4
3      |C   |   1    | 201 | 1
4      |D   |   5    | 145 | 10
```

And `tb_Cri` as follows :

```
id_criteria |name     | weight |
1           |distance | 10
2           |price    | 20
3           |quantity | 30
```

Now i want to insert data dynamically from `tb_A` into `tb_B` with structure as follows :

```
# |id_alt | id_criteria | value 
1 | 1     |   1         |  2
2 | 1     |   2         |  10
3 | 1     |   3         |  3
4 | 2     |   1         |  4
5 | 2     |   2         |  123
6 | 2     |   3         |  4
7 | 3     |   1         |  1
8 | 3     |   2         |  201
9 | 3     |   3         |  1
10| 4     |   1         |  5
11| 4     |   2         |  145
12| 4     |   3         |  10
```

How can i achieve this through PHP?

Here's what i tried so far :

```php
$data = $obj->selTable("SELECT * FROM tbb_Alt");
//$finishArr = transposeArr($data);
$totalLoop = count($data)*3;
$interval = (int)$totalLoop/3;
$counter = $totalLoop+$interval;
$j = 0;
$k = 0;
for($i=0;$i<=$counter;$i++){
    if($i%4 !== 0){
        if($k%4 == 0) $k=1;
          // code to insert data into tb_B
          // the part where i got stuck
          echo $j.'&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$k++.'&nbsp;';

        continue;
    }
    $j++;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: This transformation seems utterly pointless. I guess some information is missing that would tell us why you would want to do this.

Comment: show us your code effort.

Comment: So you want to create a table where value = distance, price and quantity for each "name" you have in first table ? You will loose information doing this no ? But if you want to do it, just do a select in first table then do an insert for name + distance value, name + price value and name + quantity value

Comment: The basic idea would be to do 3 selects, one for each row and unite them for a insert. But I have the feeling this is just a work arround for another problem.

Comment: Okay, i guess should mention that i'm trying to implement a DSS algorithm which requires me to put value of each criteria into  `tb_B` as i've structured on my question. I will edit my question to make it more clear. Wait a sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
INSERT INTO tab_b (name,value)
  SELECT name,value FROM (
    SELECT id, 1 as id2, name,distance as value FROM tb_A
      UNION SELECT id, 2 as id2, name,price as value FROM tb_A
      UNION SELECT id, 3 as id3, name,quantity as value FROM tb_A
    ORDER BY id, id2
  ) t;
```

It's always best to use in database calculations [live example @ SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1028a/1/0)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. If it works please mark the answer as correct =)

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but i'm a litte bit confuse on how to fit that calculation into my table structure. Would you mind to see my code structure in my updated question and tell me how can i achieve the same thing with that loop i made in PHP.

Comment: I think your problem are missing indexes and a proper looping. The missing indexes is problem with our query, but since I don't know which library you use I can't help you on that front (you are looking for a simular option like the PDO::FETCH_ASSOC explained [over  here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12834411/2709069)). Looping should be much more easy that way - like [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e1e3fc8b9680d67743664db351509adcf3d48103)