# List duplicates in sql query from array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I have this query that returns 8 rows instead of 10 when the `$arr_wordids` has 10 items with duplicates.

```
SELECT abc.word, abc.HUN, def.CONTEXT as context, def.WORDID as wordid FROM def JOIN abc ON abc.ID = def.WORDID WHERE WORDID IN ("12212", "8612", "12212", "52355") AND def.USERID=10001235 AND REMOVED=0
```

Where `WORDID IN ("12212", "48612", "12212", "52355")` is actually `WHERE WORDID IN (" . implode(',', array_map('intval', $arr_wordids)) . ")` in php.

Because the IN operator removes duplicates, the result of this query is now 3 rows instead of 4.

As a demonstration I added only 4 items in the example.
What are my options about listing all?

Comment: Post-processing. Loop over input array and add fake entries to the resulting array

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, you can post process the data to get the full array.

If you can return the data from PDO using the `wordid` column as the index, this will save one step (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36621058/1213708 for details of how to do this).  If not, you can use `$data = array_column($data, null, 'wordid');` to achieve the same thing.

Then with the array of word id's to be returned and the indexed data from the database, you can build a full array of data by matching the two.  An example of which would be...

```
$arr_wordids = [ 1,2,3,1];
// Results of SQL query
$data = [1 => 'row 1', 2 => 'row 2', 3 => 'row 3'];
$arr_data = [];
foreach ( $arr_wordids as $wordid ) {
    if (isset($data[$wordid])) {
        $arr_data[] = $data[$wordid];
    }
}

print_r($arr_data);
```

which with the sample data gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => row 1
    [1] => row 2
    [2] => row 3
    [3] => row 1
)
```

Comment: I wish I understood what you're saying but I don't. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Which bits don't you understand.